# Zoom на RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, gallery

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сделал галерею с помощью RecyclerView по [этому примеру](http://plattysoft.com/2015/06/16/snapping-items-on-a-horizontal-list). Не могу понять, как туда добавить увеличение на центральном элементе, как на картинке?

Comment: добавить увеличение - не проблема. Проблема состоит в том, чтобы определить, какой элемент - центральный. И для этой задачи подходит не `RecyclerView`, а `ViewPager`

Comment: Вот подробный пример как это сделать на `ViewPager`: [Горизонтальная галерея с увеличением для Android](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/489210/17609)

Comment: А на `RecyclerView` вам нужно анимировать элементы, когда они прокручиваются к середине экрана. Т.е. вам нужен `onScrollListener` в коем вы сможете через `LayoutManager` получить отображаемые элементы, узнать их координаты и отталкиваясь от размеров экрана вычислить, находятся ли они посередине. Это сложнее, чем через `ViewPager` делать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел вот такое решение. Класс SnappingRecyclerView заменяет собой RecyclerView и делает все что нужно - горизонтальную прокрутку с привязкой к центру и увеличением.

https://gist.github.com/lauw/fc84f7d04f8c54e56d56#file-snappingrecyclerview-java-L19