# Как сделать горизонтальное перелистование элементов ListView?

Tags: java, android, listview

Есть `ListView`, которые формируется через `CursorAdapter` из БД.

Как сделать, чтобы перейдя внутрь любого элемента списка и чтобы перейти к другому, не нужно было выходить снова к списку, а просто листать, вправо или влево, перемещаясь таким образом по `ListView`?

Comment: обьясните понятнее, покажите пример. Не понятно, чего вы хотите

Comment: Список:
- Поэма
- Стих
- Еще одна поэма
- Еще один стих

Заходишь в Поэма и чтобы перейти к Стих не надо выходить снова к списку, а делаешь свап влево и листаешь к новому элементу - к Стиху, от него к Еще одна поэма.

Как в этом видео - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xM3CgZ1XrhI, только элементы "1", "2" и т.д. брались из списка Listview.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/489394/191270 посмотрите здесь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте ViewPager:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
 android:id="@+id/pager"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

в `onCreate`:

```
pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
pager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter);
```

свой адаптер (например):

```
private class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return PageFragment.newInstance(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }
}
```

сама страница:

```
public class PageFragment extends Fragment {  

static PageFragment newInstance(int number) {
   Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
   PageFragment fragment = new PageFragment();
   arguments.putInt("number", number);
   fragment.setArguments(arguments);
   return pageFragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  int number = getArguments().getInt("number");    
  ...создать вашу страницу в зависимости от ее номера 

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
  Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...    
    return myPageView;
  }
}
```

Comment: Т.е. с помощью этого можно подхватить элементы из Listview и использовать их в качестве страниц для листания?

Comment: Да. Пэйджер для листания и сделан)

Answer (score 0):

Для горизонтального списка используют не ViewPager, а RecyclerView.
Пример инициализации:

```
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

Адаптер для него унаследуется от RecyclerView.Adapter. Пример :

```
public class CustomAdpater extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdpater.ViewHolder>
```