# CardView как отобразить немного следующего элемента

Tags: android, recyclerview, cardview

Использую `RecyclerView` и `CardView` нужно чтобы на экране было виден один элемент а также и кусочки предыдущего и следующего.

ВОПРОС: Как отобразить данный эффект используя `RecyclerView` и `CardView`?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 **recycler view**
 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/home_user" />


**cardView**
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/cardview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    app:cardCornerRadius="5dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_sidebar_currency" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_title"
        style="@style/menu_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="9"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Перевод и перевод перевод" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Посмотрите сюда, просто замените на кард Вью и все. Старый пример, но думаю ещё актуален.
 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/489394/191270

Comment: я использую `cardview`, мне лишь надо сделать такой же стиль пролистывания но с `recyclerview`

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите вот эту библиотеку https://github.com/moondroid/CoverFlow . Думаю, она реализует именно то, что вам нужно)

Comment: Спасибо за предложение, но я больше ищу вариант чтобы мои элементы списка лежали на одной плоскости, если это можно так назвать.